# Erro no campo de search com autocomplete - PHP / AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, banco-de-dados

Boa tarde galera, hoje consegui dar uma andamento no meu código e cheguei ao ponto onde devo estar errando em algo besta mas não consigo achar. Estou fazendo um campo input com search e autocomplete, onde o usuário irá procurar o nome do Fornecedor e ao selecionar o nome, ao lado deve popular também o CNPJ do mesmo. No momento, está dando um erro ao tentar fazer a busca pelo nome, e creio que está na API que busca os dados. Como faço para arrumar este problema na API e para conseguir popular ao lado do Nome, o CNPJ do fornecedor escolhido ?

Código do index:

```php
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Testando API</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- IMPUT NORMAL SETANDO O ID DA LISTA COM AS OPÇÕES DO AUTOCOMPLETE NO ATRIBUTO 'list'-->
<input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" list="listaFornecedores">

<!-- LISTA QUE FOI SETADA NO ARIBUTO 'list' DO INPUT-->
<datalist id="listaFornecedores">


<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script>
    init();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Código da API:

```php
<?php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '';
$dbname = 'testevip';

$connect = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

$letras = $_GET['letras'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM fornecedores WHERE nome LIKE '{$letras}%' ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT 30";
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect, $query));

if($result == NULL)
    return 'Nenhum resultado encontrado';

foreach ($result as $key => $fornecedor) {
    $json[] = $fornecedor;
}
return json_encode($json);
?>
```

Código AJAX / JS:

```js
function init(){
    $("#nome").keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val() != ""){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "API.php",
                data: {
                    "letras": $(this).val()
                },
                dataType:'json',
                //CASO DÊ TUDO CERTO
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    //LIMPA A LISTA
                    $("#listaFornecedores").empty();
                    //PREENCHE A LISTA
                    $("#listaFornecedores").append(data);
                },
                error : function(request,error)
                {
                    alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Print do erro:

http://prntscr.com/nr3lis

Agradeço desde já a qualquer ajuda fornecida !!

Comment: provavelmente falta o dataType: "json", no cabeçalho do Ajax.

Comment: Não está faltando, está ali no cabeçalho.

Comment: Já imprimiu o json lá no arquivo PHP?

Comment: Sim, mas ele está me dando um erro na minha Query, e mesmo eu mudando ela, não consigo acerta-la. Por isso pedi a ajuda, pois tenho certeza que estou errando em algo bobo na API mas não consigo identificar. Ao dar um print_r(), ele apresenta o seguinte erro:  Notice: Undefined index: letras in C:\wamp64\www\Projeto_vale_vip\API.php on line 9

Comment: dê um `echo` na query e teste-a diretamente no Banco

Comment: No Banco ela trouxe os nomes com êxito, funcionou normalmente.

Comment: Então você está criando o json incorretamente

Answer (score 0):

Com a utilização do Ajax não se utiliza **return**.

Substitua a linha:

```
return json_encode($json);
```

Para:

```
echo json_encode($json);
```

Para casos onde o json está retornando null é devido a acentuação do elemento, é necessário utilizar **utf8_encode** para exibição.